# How to pass an Array to another function with the triple...dot notation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two functions wich take an array as argument by using the `...array` triple dot notation. So that I can use the function in this way: `Foo('a', 'b', 'c')`.

The problem I am facing is that when I pass the arguments of the first to the second function I get a type error.

> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

The problem can be solved by removing the dots before the argument, but then I have to pass the arguments like this `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Which is not an option for me. So I am wondering if there is a way to pass the entire array to another function with the `...` notation.

```
function Foo(...array: string[]) {}

function Test(...array: string[]) {
    Foo(array) // This is where it starts complaining
}
```

So I what I want is to pass the arguments of `Foo` to the function `Test`, without removing the `...` notation.

Comment: If you already pass spread array then you don't need to define spread array  as a parameter in your method.
try this 

    `function Foo(array: any) {}

    function Test(array: string[]) {
        Foo(...array) // This is where it starts complaining
    }`

Comment: I try to avoid using `any` as much as possible, because I am building a library with full-blown type safety.

Comment: Then u can  use `string[]` instead of `any` :) but this scenario you may need `any` type. That's why they introduced `any`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple: just spread them.

```
function Test(...array: string[]) {
    Foo(...array);
}
```

Foo expects 0 or more arguments of type `string`. Without the spread operator, you'd pass it an array of strings instead.

Comment: That was an easy fix :) , I allready tried to completly re-implement `Foo` in `Test` to make the code compile. But don't need to anymore.